# Cannot find correct element with same class name

Tags: html, xpath

I have the following HTML snippet:

```
<div id="result-1">
  <div class="page">
    <div class="collapsingblock">
      <h4>Click Me</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="collapsingblock collapsed">
      <h4>No, Click Me</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I'm trying to do, is to find the second `collapsingblock` and it's `h4`

I have the following:

`(//div[@id="result-1"]/div[@class="page"]/div[@class="collapsingblock"])[2]/h4`

My xPath doesn't return the element. If I replace it with `[1]` it finds the first instance of `collapsingblock` though

Any ideas?

Thanks

UPDATE:

I have just noticed, that the HTML is using JavaScript to add/remove an additional class to the second `collapsingblock`, which `collapsed`

Comment: "collapsingblock" is not equal to "collapsingblock collapsed". That's the reason the element isn't being selected. How are you expecting it to be matched? Do you want to check if the value contains "collapsingblock"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the value of the `class` attribute of the second inner `div` element is *not* equal to "collapsingblock", as you can see:

```
<div class="collapsingblock collapsed">
  <h4>No, Click Me</h4>
</div>
```

Even though `class` has very clear-cut semantics in HTML, it does not mean anything special to XPath, it's an attribute like any other.

Use `contains()` to avoid this problem:

```
(//div[@id="result-1"]/div[@class="page"]/div[contains(@class,"collapsingblock")])[2]/h4
```

Then, the only result of the expression above is

```
<h4>No, Click Me</h4>
```

By the way, parentheses around the lefthand part of the expression are **not** necessary in this case:

```
//div[@id="result-1"]/div[@class="page"]/div[contains(@class,"collapsingblock")][2]/h4
```

will do exactly the same, given this particular input document.

Answer (score 0):

the parenthesis is necessary because of priority :

```
(//div[@id="result-1"]/div[@class="page"]/div[@class="collapsingblock"])[2]/h4
```

Comment: That's what I thought and its why I added it in

Comment: what about `(//div[@class="collapsingblock"])[2]/h4` ?